# How can I avoid using async in lambda expression of ContinueWith()

Tags: c#

In my current unit test code to test my ASP controller, I have

```
var resp = aController.Get();
string stringContent = await resp.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Where signature of aController.Get() is

```
public IHttpActionResult Get()
```

Now I need to change the signature of Get() to

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAsync()
```

So I change my above test code to:

```
aController.GetAsync().ContinueWith(
    async (t) =>
    {
        var actionResult = t.Result;
        string stringContent = await actionResult.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
});
```

My question is if it is a good practice to have `async` in the lambda expression in the ContinueWith() usage.

Another way to do this is

```
string stringContent = await aController.Get().Result.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None).Result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I think that is not very readable either.  I wonder if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Personally, the second version with await is more readable.

Comment: Does this actually run? noticing a blocking calls

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Second option has a blocking call where you force `Result` to be retrieved.I would suggest doing it in three statements:

```
var result = await aController.GetAsync();
var result2 = await result.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken.None);
string stringContent = await result2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If you still want to make some synchronous calls, I would say then ditch the async idea for good. Because it is a compromise you are making and not gaining anything in value.

Comment: My proposed code is fully async. The code you wrote is somewhat half sync, half async, so what I meant is - if you are using async/await or Task/ContinueWith, you should not call ".Result" because that just makes any async call a blocking call. No value in that.